# Binomial theorem: divisibility by $n^2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Consider $X = (a+b)^n-a^n-b^n$  where

- $a$ and $b$ and $a+b$ are not divisible by $n$,
- $n>=3$ is positive and prime,
- $a \ne b$ and both are greater than 1.

By the binomial expansion we know $X$ is divisible by $n$, but how can we study whether $X$ is divisible by $n^2$ or other powers of $n$?

Specifically I am interested to prove $X$ is NOT divisible by $n^2$, but I am not sure how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: I believe it can go either way. Take $n=2$ for instance. We have $(1+1)^2-1^2-1^2 = 2$ while $(1+2)^2-1^2-2^2 = 4$.

Comment: OK, I need to add more information to the question.

Comment: I believe it can go either way. Take $n=3$ for instance. We have $(2+3)^3-2^3-3^3 = 90$ while $(2+5)^3-2^3-5^3 = 210$.

Comment: :D OK. Let me think how to clarify the question. There are more properties to a and b that I escaped.

Comment: @player3236 one thing about your last comment: $3$ is divisible by $3$, so that does not count. And in the second example with 2 and 5, 210 is not divisible by 9. So my hypothesis holds.

Comment: Oops. Should have went with $(2+4)^3 - 2^3-4^3 = 144$ instead.

Comment: Attempting to identify *satisfying* values for $a,b,n$ seems problematic.
For each $k$ in $\{1,2,\cdots,[n-1]\}$, you have to first
study the residue $\pmod{n^2}$ of $\binom{n}{k}$, and then study the residue
$\pmod{n^2}$ of $\binom{n}{k} a^k b^{(n-k)}$.

Comment: A decently short proof will show that a necessary condition for your expression to not be divisible by $n^2$ is that $a+b$ is not divisible by $n$. I'm not sure if it is sufficient, but it is for $n=3$.

Comment: @player3236 In fact $a$ and $b$ are odd numbers and $a+b$ is not divisible by $n$.

Comment: Now after some searching, I found that $7^3 \mid (15+11)^7-15^7-11^7$. What are you trying to prove? Perhaps there is another way. BTW this is found by the factorization $(a+b)^7-a^7-b^7 = 7ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)^2$.

Comment: There always exist values of $a$, $b$ such that $n^2$ divides the expression when $n\equiv 1$ mod $3$. There are some values of $n\equiv 2$ mod $3$ for which $a$, $b$ exist. Have a look at https://oeis.org/A068209.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julian Rosen figured it out in the comments. I'm just going to explain what's going on in the OEIS and the linked website, which is Kevin Brown's.

You can eliminate one of the variables by

$$(a+b)^n-a^n-b^n\equiv 0 \mod n^2$$

$$b^{-n}(a+b)^n-b^{-n}a^n-1\equiv 0$$

Now let $x\equiv ab^{-1}$

$$(x+1)^n-x^n-1\equiv 0$$

It's easy to check by expanding the binomial that if $x\equiv y\mod n$ then  $(x+1)^n-x^n-1\equiv (y+1)^n-y^n-1\mod n^2$, so I'm just going to look at $x\equiv 0,1,2\dots n-1$.

This has trivial solutions when $x\equiv 0,-1\mod n$.

Now I'll prove that if $n\equiv 1\mod 6$ then there are other solutions. $(x+1)^n-x^n-1$ is a multiple of $x^2+x+1$. This follows from the fact that the roots of the second are also roots of the first:

$$x^2+x+1=0\implies x=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}2$$

These are cubic roots of unity, plus $x+1=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{-3}}2$ are sixth roots of unity. Since all primes greater than 3 are $\pm 1 \mod 6$ it suffices to prove it for $n=5,7$ and the other cases follow by reducing mod 6.

The equation:

$$x^2+x+1\equiv 0\mod n$$

Is solvable when $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod n.

$$(2x+1)^2\equiv -3$$

Which in turn happens when $n\equiv 1 \mod 6$. So the only cases that may not have solutions are $n\equiv -1$. A few of them do though, [as listed on OEIS](http://oeis.org/A068209) the first being 59. So your question is hard, probably has no known solution and isn't solvable by elementary methods.

Furthermore, if $x$ is a solution to the equation then so are $x^{-1}$ and $-1-x$. You can compose those and find $-1-x^{-1}$ and $(-1-x)^{-1}$ and so on until you find that they wrap around getting you at most 6 solutions. The times when you don't get 6 are: the trivial solutions $0,-1$, the pair of solutions of $x^2+x+1\equiv 0$, and the trio $1,-2,-2^{-1}$. Morgan Rodgers proves this for me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3864068/336056). That last trio of solutions occur when

$$2^n\equiv 2 \mod n^2$$

Which is the definition of a Wieferich prime.

Comment: Interesting to see this question is actually linked to FLT and has been studied extensively. Thank you and Julian Rosen for the answer.

It took me some time to read the articles, especially this one: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath367/kmath367.htm
but it gives a nice background information and good discussions.