# The congruence $a^p+b^p\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;p^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For each prime $p$, let
$
X_p=\{(a,b)\in\{1,...,p-1\}^2{\,{\large{\mid}}\,}a^p+b^p\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;p^2)\}
$.

Based on limited data testing, the following conjectures appear to hold:

  $(1)\;\;X_p\ne{\large{\varnothing}}\;$
  for all primes
  $\;p\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;6)$
  .
  $(2)\;\;X_p={\large{\varnothing}}\;$for infinitely many primes$\;p\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;6)$.

Any thoughts about the validity of these claims?

Comment: One obvious observation is that $a+b \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: As noted previously, this congruence can only happen if $b\equiv 1-a$ mod $p$, meaning that $b=p+1-a$. But $(p+1-a)^p\equiv (1-a)^p\mod p^2$, so your question is equivalent to asking when $a^p + (1-a)^p\equiv 1$ mod $p^2$, which is essentially equivalent to [this recent MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852322/binomial-theorem-divisibility-by-n2#comment7948854_3852322).

Comment: @Julian Rosen: That reduction makes sense, and based on the link you provided, it seems that my questions are effectively answered. Thanks to all. Should I now delete the question?

Comment: You shouldn't delete. I think the protocol is that if this question is really a duplicate of the linked question, it should be marked as such. But I think it is at least not obviously a duplicate, so probably what should happen is that someone should write an answer explaining what is going on and post it here. I don't have the energy to do that at the moment, but if nobody else does, I might come back later and post an answer.

Comment: @quasi Per your comment, I have closed this question as a duplicate of the linked question.  Please let me know if this contravenes your intentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer. We have

$$(x + kp)^p \equiv x^p + {p \choose 1} x^{p-1} kp \equiv x^p \bmod p^2$$

which gives that if $a \equiv b \bmod p$ then $a^p \equiv b^p \bmod p^2$. (A special case of [lifting the exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma).) Reducing the equation $\bmod p$ gives $a + b \equiv 1 \bmod p$, hence

$$a^p + b^p \equiv a^p + (1 - a)^p \equiv 1 \bmod p^2.$$

We know that this always holds $\bmod p$ so to investigate it $\bmod p^2$ we need to investigate the behavior of the function $D(a) = \frac{a^p - a}{p} \bmod p$. This is a function from $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p$, and the above equation is equivalent to $D(a) + D(1 - a) \equiv 0 \bmod p$.

> **Lemma:** $D$ satisfies $D(ab) = D(a) b + a D(b)$. (So it's almost a derivation, except that it isn't additive.)

*Proof.* We have $(a^p - a)(b^p - b) \equiv 0 \bmod p^2$, which gives

$$(ab)^p - a b^p - a^p b + ab \equiv 0 \bmod p^2.$$

Rearranging this a bit gives

$$(ab)^p - ab \equiv a(b^p - b) + (a^p - a) b \bmod p^2$$

which is the desired identity. $\Box$

From here we need to assume that $p$ is odd, so note that the case $p = 2$ can be done by hand: we have $a^2 \equiv 0, 1 \bmod 4$ so the equation has no nontrivial solutions. Now suppose $p$ is odd so that $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ has a primitive root $g$. Induction gives

$$D(g^n) = ng^{n-1} D(g)$$

which determines $D$ in terms of $D(g)$ on $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2)^{\times}$. Note that $D(g) = g \frac{g^{p-1} - 1}{p}$ is invertible $\bmod p^2$. It remains to determine $D$ on $p \mathbb{Z}/p^2$, but this is easy: if $a = pk$ then $D(a) \equiv -k \bmod p$. Now we split into cases.

**Case 1:** $1 - a \in p \mathbb{Z}/p^2$. Write $a = 1 + kp$, so $a \equiv 1 \bmod p$ gives $a^p \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$, so $D(a) = 0$ and $D(1 - a) = k$, which gives

$$D(a) + D(1 - a) \equiv k \equiv 0 \bmod p.$$

This gives $a \equiv 1 \bmod p^2, b \equiv 0 \bmod p^2$ so there are no nontrivial solutions in this case. By symmetry this also takes care of the case that $a \in p \mathbb{Z}/p^2$.

**Case 2:** Neither $a$ nor $1 - a$ is in $p \mathbb{Z}/p^2$. Then they're both powers of $g$. Write $a = g^n, 1 - a = g^m$, where $1 \le n, m \le p(p-1)$. Then

$$D(a) + D(1 - a) = ng^{n-1} D(g) + mg^{m-1} D(g) \equiv 0 \bmod p.$$

Dividing by $D(g)$ and multiplying by $g$ we get the system of equations

$$\boxed{ g^n + g^m \equiv 1 \bmod p^2 \\ ng^n + mg^m \equiv 0 \bmod p. }$$

Equivalently, write $\log_g$ for the discrete logarithm $\log_g g^n = n$ on $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2)^{\times}$, taking values in $\mathbb{Z}/(p(p-1))$. Then the equation $D(a) + D(1-a) \equiv 0 \bmod p$ becomes

$$\boxed{ a \log_g(a) + (1 - a) \log_g(1 - a) \equiv 0 \bmod p }.$$

This is a funny kind of "entropy $\bmod p$," so maybe Leinster's *[Entropy modulo a prime](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06961)* is relevant.

**Edit:** Looking at the linked question it looks like I made things too hard for myself. If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ then we can take $a = \omega$ to be a primitive sixth root of unity $\bmod p^2$. This gives $1 - a = 1 - \omega = - \omega^2$ and hence

$$a^p + (1 - a)^p \equiv \omega^p + (-\omega^2)^p \equiv \omega - \omega^2 \equiv 1 \bmod p^2.$$

We have $- \omega^2 = \omega^{-1}$ which suggests taking $m = -n$. At this point it becomes clear that I made a mistake earlier (which has now been fixed): I assumed that $m, n$ couldn't be divisible by $p$, but this isn't true and in fact if $p \mid m, n$ then the second equation is trivial. If $a = \omega$ is a primitive sixth root of unity $\bmod p^2$ then $a = g^n$ where $n = \frac{p(p-1)}{6}$ and in particular $p \mid n$.